# Ubuntu 18.04 USB 3 flash being seen as a USB 2

Tags: 18.04, usb

my system doesn't seem to recognize my USB 3.0 flash. It instead claims to be a 2.0. Any help would be appreciated!

My usb flash is Kingston 16GB DataTraveler Micro 3.1

I have ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS with Kernel 5.0.10-050010-generic.

I added iommu=soft to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT or GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX but not working.

Even I update my kernel from 4.15.0-45.48 to 5.0.10-050010-generic but not working.

I searched in google and tested all the solutions but none of the answers worked.

I have dual boot windows and ubuntu. In my windows I plugged in my  usb3 flash abd works fine.but in ubuntu not. here is the output of lsusb -t

```
lsusb -t
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/9p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
```

Comment: I mean Ubuntu knows laptop has USB 3 but when  I plugged in my USB 3 Ubuntu seen it as USB 2!

Answer (score 1):

Your output shows USB 3.0 on Bus 03 running at 5000 Mbps (5 Million bits per second).

Breaking down the USB speeds I'll use my system:

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Printer, Driver=usblp, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 10, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 10, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

- Bus 04: USB 3.1, 10,000 Mbps (10 Gbps)
- Bus 03: USB 2.0, 480 Mbps
- Bus 02: USB 3.0, 5,000 Mbps (5 Gbps)
- Bus 01, Port 4, Device 10: USB 1.0 12 Mbps

Comment: I mean Ubuntu knows laptop has USB 3 but when  I plugged in my USB 3 Ubuntu seen it as USB 2!

Comment: Make sure you are using a USB 3 cable (usually blue) and not a USB 2 cable (usually black)

Comment: My flash and laptop port both of them are blue and usb3. I'm sure because in my windows os with same state it's work as usb3. I think the problem is more complicated. Maybe it's want some change on kernel. I don't know.

Comment: @hossein Can you update your question with the model of your USB 3.0 flash drive? Also can you update your question to show where Linux states it is using USB 3.0 speeds?

Comment: Yes of course, I updated the question about my flash model. but what do you mean about 'show where Linux states it is using USB 3.0 speeds' ?

Comment: @hossein Others have had problems with your particular USB flash drive only running at USB 2.0 speeds and not USB 3.0 speed. I have to run off to work but here is a little something to read: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/can%27t-mount-usb-3-0-flash-drive-will-mount-in-usb-2-0-port-though-4175619828/page2.html